# How Can I Configure an Oracle Data Source in Lightswitch to Map Tables Owned by Another User?

Tags: oracle, configuration, datasource, visual-studio-lightswitch

We are using a SaaS provider at my company, who also offers direct read-only access to their back end Oracle database.

Our Oracle user does not *own* any of the tables, therefore the tables we want to read belong to other users.  So the tables must be addressed as follows: OwnerUser.table1, OwnerUser.table2, etc.

When setting up a data source in LightSwitch, no tables are visible, because the Entity Data Model is mapping to tables owned by our user (the one which we connect with).

Does anyone know if I can tweak the data source somewhere to inject the owner prefix (e.g. OwnerUser) so that the LightSwitch Designer will show the tables owned by OwnerUser?

Answer (score 1):

You might find that in this case it might be easier to create a custom RIA Service layer for the datasource that passes the user information and sets up the tables.

Comment: That is always your 'get out of jail card' :)

Comment: @Mykre Can you post a link to a doc where I can learn how to create a custom RIA Service Layer?  I am not sure I know what that is.